# How to implement nested event listeners in js

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, submit

I am building a text adventure game that takes in user input and guides the player down a tree like structure. My thought process is to have one main event listener listening for a submit action that will start the game. I then proceeded to add another event listener based on the initial response, but nothing happens.

Is nesting event listeners even the proper way to handle this situation?

```
//prompts
const bed = 'Your lack of desire has lead you towards a life of bordeom and dread. [[GAME OVER]]'.split('');
const explore = 'As your eyes adjust to the early monning sun, you glance around the room. To your left, you notice a small, but sturdy bed side table. In front of you, a TV is broadcasting re-runs of the show "Friends". You also consider walking and exploring more of this strange room.What is your next inclination?'.split('')
const walkAroundRoom = 'Walking around the room seems like a good idea. After all, you tell yourself, "I should at least aquainte and introduce myself to this bewildering experience. After a bit of pondering and wandering, you look straight ahead and notice a bathroom. To your right, a window.'.split('')

submit.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  if (response('bed')) {
    go(bed)
  } else if (response('ex')) {
    go(explore)

    submit.addEventListener('submit',()=>{
      if(response('tv')){
        go(watchTV)
      } else if(response('walk')){
        go(walkAroundRoom)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an object, whose keys uniquely identify a set of text and the values contain the text to display and the prompt keys each possible response would point to. This way, you only have to add a single listener:

```js
const prompts = {
  wake: {
    text: 'You wake, enter "walk" or "explore"',
    responses: { walk: 'wake_walk', explore: 'wake_explore' }
  },
  wake_explore: {
    text: 'You explore after waking. Enter "walk" to walk',
    responses: { walk: 'wake_walk' }
  },
  wake_walk: {
    text: 'You walk. Enter "walk" to continue walking, or "sleep" to go back to sleep',
    responses: { walk: 'wake_walk', sleep: 'sleep' }
  },
  sleep: {
    text: 'You sleep.',
    responses: {}
  }
};

const [div, input, button, errors] = document.querySelectorAll('div, input, button');
let lastResponses;
const displayPrompt = ({ text, responses }) => {
  div.textContent = text;
  lastResponses = responses;
};
displayPrompt(prompts.wake);

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const nextPrompt = prompts[lastResponses[input.value]];
  if (nextPrompt) {
    displayPrompt(nextPrompt);
    errors.textContent = '';
  } else {
    errors.textContent = 'Action not possible now';
  }
  input.value = '';
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<input>
<button>submit</button>
<div></div>
```

The semi-permanent `lastResponses` is there to hold the last response object so that the same action can be entered in different situations, while pointing to different `prompts` keys. (eg, you could `walk` after getting up, and also `walk` when on the street, and not have those actions collide)